# Getting other applications usage details and battery usage information - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I want to perform two tasks:

1. Show the frequently used applications according to a specific time.
2. Want to perform some analysis on the battery usage by every application.

I have seen lots of similar question but didn't get a specific answer. 
I have also seen some apps which performs theses tasks. SO, I was wondering that how can it be accomplished.
(Ref 1 : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18774/what-are-my-most-frequently-used-apps)

(Ref 2: [How to get information about android battery usage by application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770021/how-to-get-information-about-android-battery-usage-by-application) -In this link, there is an answer but the links are dead)

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for stating the fact that I know !!!. I just want to know that are these two tasks programatically  possible or not ?