# how to get the battery usage details of installed apps?

Tags: android, battery, usage-statistics, installed-applications

Using this code, I can find the battery level of the phone:

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float percent = (level / (float)scale) * 100;
```

But how do I get the battery usage details of apps installed on phone, including that of the screen, as shown in the image below?

[image: Screenshot of battery usage details screen]

Comment: Need to get the Individual app wise battery usage details

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770021/how-to-get-information-about-android-battery-usage-by-application

Comment: @VivekMishra i need to get programmaticaly not by adb command

Comment: see chris answer from that link

Comment: @Edgarprabhu - I checked out the link and it definitely has what you're looking for.

Comment: @VivekMishra - you should make this an answer.

Comment: @KristyWelsh posted as answer

Answer (score 3):

Measuring the power consumption for an specific app or for a specific part of the phones hardware is not that easy. From the public Google Developer API it is not possible to do this on an easy way. There are other ways which are quiet complicated. For every Android smart-phone Google requires the manufacturer to add a so called [power profile](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/) XML to an device. They look like this

```
  <item name="screen.on">0.1</item>  <!-- ~200mA -->
  <item name="screen.full">0.1</item>  <!-- ~300mA -->
  <item name="bluetooth.active">0.1</item> <!-- Bluetooth data transfer, ~10mA -->
  <item name="bluetooth.on">0.1</item>  <!-- Bluetooth on & connectable, but not connected, ~0.1mA -->
  <item name="wifi.on">0.1</item>  <!-- ~3mA -->
  <item name="wifi.active">0.1</item>  <!-- WIFI data transfer, ~200mA -->
  <item name="wifi.scan">0.1</item>
```

They tell you how much current each hardware state of a component consumes (e.g. Wifi has three states, the CPU has 10 etc). Now Android is Linux based and this allows you the check the current state of each hardware component. For example the file

```
/sys/devices/virtual/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
```

gives you the current state of your LCD (notice that for this **no** root access is required). For every hardware component such an path exists. If you now want to exactly measure how much energy an app consumes, you need to write a service which monitors whenever the app is active or not and what are the current hardware states. With this information you can compute the energy consumption.

There also exists an app which is open source, it is called [PowerTutor](http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/) (here is th [Play-Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.umich.PowerTutor) and her you'll find the [source code](https://github.com/msg555/PowerTutor). It does exactly what I just explained. They also publish a scientific [paper](http://robertdick.org/publications/zhang10oct.pdf) on how accurate their approach is (it does a good job).

Now comes the problem. Some years ago I had the problem of measuring the power consumption of some apps. A customer wanted us to evaluate their exact power consumption. In the end we found out that the power profiles on which the analysis is based are not accurate enough. It seemed that the manufacturers are just putting some values in the XML which are not even related to the device. We had over 100 different devices from 20 different brands only a few of them seemed to have values in their XML which were related to the device.

Finally I can say, don't spend to much time on measuring the real power consumption on the software side, it's not worth the effort. Use a real Multimeter and measure the hardware directly.

Answer (score 1):

Battery stats can be dumped from the device like this for API >= 19:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats
```

For API < 19, use:

```
adb shell dumpsys batteryinfo
```

Comment: seems like this has changed to `adb shell dumpsys batterystats`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection to access some private members and methods, I would recommend you to program in source code environment, which allow you to use any private API.

If you also want to include the internal classes or methods, do the following:

1. Go to /platforms/.
2. Copy, paste and replace the downloaded hidden API file into this directory, e.g. android-23/android.jar.
3. Change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23 (for example).
4. Finally, rebuild your project.

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api