# How to extract battery usage data via recovery or something else

Tags: android, adb, root

There is a battery stat in Android (Settings - Battery). For example:

- Idle - 30 %
- Screen - 10 %
- BT - 5 %
- Chrome - 25 %
- Camera - 5 %

Where is the data located? I need somehow to extract this data via a file manager (I have ROOT) or ADB or TWRP.

**UPD**: I don't think this is a duplicate of [How to get information about android battery usage by application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770021/how-to-get-information-about-android-battery-usage-by-application) because that question is old and the answer isn't relevant today.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, as this question is specifically about accessing this data as root, while the other one is about using the SDK.